# Understanding postgreSQL's ident, md5, password in pg_hba.conf

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, database, postgresql

If I have the following in my `pg_hba.conf`

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD
local   all         all                               trust
local   all         all                               ident
host    rt4         rt_user     127.0.0.1/32          md5
host    rt4         rt_user     127.0.0.1/32          password
```

When I don't have anything in `pg_ident.conf`, is the second `local` rule then obsolete?

Is the first `host` line overruled by the second?

As the client (web application) will connect to the database using `localhost`, does it then matter whether I choose `md5` or `password`? I mean, is the authentication method an abstraction layer, so the client doesn't know how the password was checked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the postgresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html):

> The first record with a matching connection type, client address,
>   requested database, and user name is used to perform authentication.
>   There is no "fall-through" or "backup": if one record is chosen and
>   the authentication fails, subsequent records are not considered. If no
>   record matches, access is denied.

Having two lines that are completely similar except for only the authentication will not work the way you like - only the first line will be used. So yes, the second `local`rule is obsolete. So is the second `host` line; it will never override the first.